# Notepad++: Double Click on Tabs bar to open new file

Tags: notepad++, tabs

Most browsers. editors, IDEs that are tab-enabled allow for new file to be opened (like Ctrl+N) when we double-click next to the last tab, can this be enabled in Np++ ?

Comment: It works with at least version `v7.5.8`

Comment: That's the exact same version I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default behaviour for my Notepad++ version 7, but I could not find settings related to this.  Maybe try to do a reset?

Comment: I take it that means deleting config files ?? Sigh...so many of them...Update - yep that worked...thanks (deleted stylers & config for future ref.)